# argp_parse segfaults when a source file contains a GTK application callback

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk, argp

I am trying to work on a project that emulates the 6502 microprocessor, and for that I want to get a GUI working that is launched from the command line with several command line arguments. I'm using the argp header to parse command line arguments, and GTK for the GUI.

Here's a snippet of my main.c file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <argp.h>
//Other includes I maybe forgot

//Exist in main.h but have been put here for clarity
void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data);
error_t parse(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state);

error_t parse(int key, char* arg, struct argp_state* state) {
    // parse command line options and test their validity
}

void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    // do stuff here idk
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct argp_option options[4];
    //Initialize the options field (3 options + 1 zeroed struct)
    struct argp parser;
    parser->options = options;
    parser->parser = parse;
    //Segfaults during this function call
    argp_parse(&parser, argc, argv, 0, 0, NULL);

    //code would continue here...
}
```

When I have this code as-is (of course including the redactions) it segfaults in the call to argp_parse. If I comment out the definition for `activate` (the declaration however can be kept) It doesn't segfault, but this is an undesirable result of course.

I tried to rename the function to something more unusual like `let_me_use_this_function_please` (my hypothesis was that maybe some function with the same name caused problems somehow) and extracting the activate function to a separate source file didn't do the trick either. That's pretty much everything I've tried because I can't really debug the argp implementation since I'm missing the source files so I can't find out where exactly it segfaults.

Comment: Why are you allocating `argp_option` and `argp` dynamically? It is not needed. In any case, please post a [mcve]. Add back the parts that are needed to reproduce the problem, and remove the parts that are not needed to reproduce the problem. The crash happens in `argp_parse` so anything that happens before that is potentially important and everything that happens after that is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I allocated them dynamically because, well, I'm still not quite acquainted with C and only pick up on stuff that other people do, so I may not realize there are easier/simpler ways to do things. Thanks for the hint. I also removed unnecessary code like the code in `activate` and everything after `argp_parse`

Comment: Please read what it means to create a [mre] again (and again and again). `//Initialize the options field (3 options + 1 zeroed struct)` Don't replace code with comments. Include **all the code that is necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I have realized that it was because during the allocation of memory for the parser, I forgot to zero everything first (I think that was also why I used dynamic allocation instead of stack allocation). Setting both the options array and the parser struct to zero first using `memset` and then setting all my required data prevents the crash from happening. So turns out that the GTK callback was completely unrelated and it was just my lacking knowledge of how memory allocation works in C